# Cannot find symbol: implements Drawable

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, drawable, symbols

I am trying to do a custom drawing for each Gladiator object I create, then move them around. I am currently getting a cannot find symbol error inside Gladiator class on "public class Gladiator implements Drawable{" regarding keyword Drawable. I am pretty sure I am importing what I need to (likely more)...

```
public class Test2 extends JFrame {

private PaintPanel paintPanel;
public Test2() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    paintPanel = new  PaintPanel();
    getContentPane().add(paintPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
    paintPanel.initGame();
}
class PaintPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private List<Gladiator> gladiators;
    private Timer timer;

    public void initGame() {

        timer = new Timer(50, this);
        timer.start();

    }       
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
        System.out.println("Refreshing ");
    }

    public PaintPanel(){
        super();
        gladiators = new ArrayList<Gladiator>();

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        for (Gladiator s : gladiators){
            g2.draw(s);
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Test2 gamePanel = new Test2();
            gamePanel.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Gladiator class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Gladiator implements Drawable {

    int minreach = 60;
    int maxreach = 100;
    int z = maxreach * 2;
    int n = minreach * 2;
    int[] location = new int[] {25,25};

    public void Draw(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillArc(location[0], location[1], z, z, 45, 90);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillArc((location[0]+(z-n)/2),(location[1]+(z-n)/2), n, n, 45, 90);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillArc((location[0]+(z-30)/2),(location[1]+(z-30)/2), 30, 30, 0, 360);
    }
```

}

Why am I getting this error? I need to be able to draw my gladiators to screen. Do I need separate classes for my visual representation (abstract?) and my game object as some tutorials I have read seem to suggest?

Edit:

I removed drawable entirely because as I had assumed it was just part of java syntax, I may not even need it. Here is code:

```
public class Test2 extends JFrame {

private PaintPanel paintPanel;
public Test2() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    paintPanel = new  PaintPanel();
    getContentPane().add(paintPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
    paintPanel.initGame();
}
class PaintPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private List<Gladiator> gladiators;
    private Timer timer;

    public void initGame() {

        timer = new Timer(50, this);
        timer.start();

    }       
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
        System.out.println("Refreshing ");
    }

    public PaintPanel(){
        super();
        gladiators = new ArrayList<Gladiator>();

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        for (Gladiator s : gladiators){
            g2.draw(s);
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Test2 gamePanel = new Test2();
            gamePanel.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Gladiator class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Gladiator {

    int minreach = 60;
    int maxreach = 100;
    int z = maxreach * 2;
    int n = minreach * 2;
    int[] location = new int[] {25,25};

    public void Draw(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillArc(location[0], location[1], z, z, 45, 90);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillArc((location[0]+(z-n)/2),(location[1]+(z-n)/2), n, n, 45, 90);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillArc((location[0]+(z-30)/2),(location[1]+(z-30)/2), 30, 30, 0, 360);
    }
```

}

My error now is on line "g2.draw(s);" and says "actual argument Gladiator cannot be converted to Shape by method invocation conversion". Thanks for any help... how to convert my Gladiator to a shape? Or should I be extending Shape somehow?

Comment: What is the "Drawable" interface?? Where have you created this?

Comment: What's the `Drawable` interface?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels great minds thinks the same thing :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: indeed. The question boggles mine though. Where is he pulling this interface from?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels probably from some code on the net that he/she just copied/pasted but never analysed/adapted.

Comment: The danger with tutorials are that some of them are horribly, horribly outdated and as a newcomer you have no basis to filter them out, I fell into this trap. @Peter F I recommend java-gaming.org forums, start by reading some of the very well-done tutorials there.

Comment: I guess I thought it was a 'thing' in java? I have used it in the main class without problems. Did something I do there incidentally create it for me? I will read up on implementing drawable in Gladiator. Thanks

Comment: Okay, I am just going to remove drawable altogether, because I may not even need it. See above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any "thing" that is part of core Java can be found in the Java API. If you look up the API, you'll see that Drawable doesn't exist. The API should be your first place to look when you run into such errors.

---

**Edit**
You state in an edit:

> My error now is on line "g2.draw(s);" and says "actual argument Gladiator cannot be converted to Shape by method invocation conversion". Thanks for any help... how to convert my Gladiator to a shape? Or should I be extending Shape somehow?

Again, look at the API, this time at the Graphics2D class. If you use its `draw(...)` method you must follow its rules, which the API states expects a Shape. You could have your Gladiator implement Shape, but then you'll need to implement many methods. You could also have it extend one of the more concrete classes that derive from Shape.

Or perhaps what you ***really*** are trying to do is to call your draw method on your Gladiator object passing in the Graphics object.

So not:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    for (Gladiator s : gladiators){
        g2.draw(s);
    }
}
```

but rather

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    for (Gladiator s : gladiators){
        s.draw(g2);  // note draw should *not* be capitalized!
    }
}
```

Comment: "s.draw(g2);  // note draw should *not* be capitalized!"

You got me good there, Hovercraft. =P

Let me ponder this.

Comment: @PeterF: `public void Draw(Graphics g){` should instead be `public void draw(Graphics g){` since it is a method, not a constructor or class name.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was a snipe about my the other question you answered for me earlier tonight.

Answer (score 2):

Drawable is most likely an [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) the tutorial you are following implements to allow for polymorphism, for keeping all the drawables in one collection for a rendererclass to easily access and render (like you are trying to do here).

Try looking at the tutorial you are following, most likely the interface is declared there, if not you can declare it yourself. Here is a very simple example implementing an interface like the one you intend to:

```
public static interface Drawable {
    public void draw(Graphics2D g);
}

public static class BlueRectangle implements Drawable {

    private Rectangle rectangle;

    public BlueRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        Color gColor = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fill(rectangle);
        g.setColor(gColor);
    }

}

public static class RedCircle implements Drawable {

    private Ellipse2D.Double circle;

    public RedCircle(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        this.circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        Color gColor = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fill(circle);
        g.setColor(gColor);
    }

}

// This allows you to for instance create collections of Drawables for
// rendering and a renderer class that doesn't care how each specific class
// implements rendering, it just uses its graphics object to render them

public static class Renderer extends JPanel {
    List<Drawable> drawables;
    private Random random = new Random();

    public Renderer() {
        this.drawables = new ArrayList<>();
        setUpDrawAbles();
        setBackground(Color.black);
    }

    @Override
    @Transient
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(1000, 1000);
    }

    private void setUpDrawAbles() {
        // Add some circles
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Drawable circle = new RedCircle(random.nextDouble() * 1000,
                    random.nextDouble() * 1000, random.nextInt(200),
                    random.nextInt(200));
            drawables.add(circle);
        }

        // Add some rectangles;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Drawable rectangle = new BlueRectangle(random.nextInt(1000),
                    random.nextInt(1000), random.nextInt(200),
                    random.nextInt(200));
            drawables.add(rectangle);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        // This class doesn't know what a BlueRectangle or a RedCircle is,
        // it just tells them
        // "here is the graphicsobject to my canvas, use it to draw yourself"
        for (Drawable drawable : drawables) {
            drawable.draw(g2d);
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Renderer render = new Renderer();
    frame.getContentPane().add(render);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

**Edit:** Yes, it is true you may not need it at all since you only have one object (a gladiator) that needs rendering but if in the future you decide to implement alot of visual objects having a common interface for rendering will make life easier for you and addition of content much much easier and faster, it reduces interdependancy between the gamemanagers alot when they can communicate over a contract (the interface) that tells how stuff should behave and not how stuff is built.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, use a [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) for graphics since you are using Swing.

Comment: Your answer is just the opposite of true. Canvas has no automatic double buffering as opposed to JPanel or JComponent.

Comment: Either way, its not really on topic to discuss buffering, so I will edit out of my answer.

Comment: If you buffer with Canvas, you have to do it manually. It's an AWT class, as such it doesn't override paintCompoennt and has no automatic double buffering as Swing JComponents do. I still strongly urge folks not to use AWT components when Swing components are much better to use. Your answer remains wrong.

Comment: All you have to do is set a BufferStrategy... I would argue that its doing the work for you, but I see your point.

Comment: I fail to see how it is still wrong... I am simply stating what I would use at this point... This is verging on petty

Comment: He is creating a Swing GUI, and you're recommending that he use an AWT component to draw in, when Swing components work just fine and don't have side effects that can be commonly seen when mixing heavy and light weight components without care. Why add complexity for no benefit?

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I thought you were simply disliking Canvas. If there is an inherent problem due to mixing that is different. I shall revise.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it is the preferred method for java2d gamedevs. Can you imagine creating an RPG using a swing layout and paintcomponent overrides? The most common practice is to just create a canvas with a buffer and draw directly to it.